# Half Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

I have a question about Half Normal Distribution.

Suppose that $x$ is Normally Distributed with zero mean $(\mu=0)$ and variance $(0<\sigma^2 <1)$. I want to find the probability distribution function of $y=|x|$, where $|.|$ means the absolute vale. Here is what I did in *Mathematica*:

`x = TransformedDistribution[Abs[y],y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, .3]]`

Then I calculated the value of PDF of x at a point $u=0.1$ as follow:

`PDF[x, u] /. u -> .01`

and the output was:

`2.51589`

How could that happen? I mean the value of PDF of $x$ at $u=0.1$ is greater than one?

Comment: Because it's a *density*...

Comment: But how could probability density function has a value greater than 1?

Comment: This is basic probability. See, e.g., the [Further Details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details) section of PDF in Wikipedia...

Comment: Now I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: A simple example to illustrate:  Consider a uniform distribution between $0<x<1/2$.  What is the probability density function evaluated at $x = 1/4$?  Clearly $\int_0^{1/2} PDF(x) dx = 1$.  So....

Comment: Note that the area below a pdf represents probabilities, not the value that the pdf takes at this or the other point. hence the values that pdf takes are not bounded to be smaller than one. Of course pdf (being sort of a historgram) can not take negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF of $X$ is $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}),$ for real $x$.

The PDF of $Y = |X|$ is $f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}),$ for $y \ge 0,$ and $f_Y(y) = 0,$ for $y < 0.$

If $\sigma = .3,$ we have $f_Y(0.1) = 2.515888.$
The standard deviation is relatively small, so probability is
concentrated near 0 and the density function at .1 is relatively large.
However, $\int_0^\infty f_Y(y)\,dy = 1$ and 
$0 \le F_Y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f_Y(y)\,dy \le 1,$ for all real $t.$

Comment: the negative sign should be an equality :-) I just corrected it but it somehow got back, sorry for not letting you know beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, which was made before I was done proofreading. Hope it's correct now.